# How do I show that this square matrix has this relationship?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Given a square matrix $M$, I have

$$\exp M = 1 + \sum^{\infty}_{n=1}\frac{M^n}{n!}$$

for the matrix

$$ M = \begin{bmatrix}
0 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 1\\
0 & -1 & 0
\end{bmatrix}$$

and any real number $\theta$, I want to show a)

$$\exp\theta M = 1 + M\sin \theta + M^2 (1-\cos \theta)$$

and hence show that b)
$$\exp\theta_1 M \ \exp\theta_2 M = \exp(\theta_1 + \theta_2) M$$

and finally show that c)

$$(\exp\theta M ) ( \exp \theta M)^T = 1$$

Thoughts:

1. I'm a bit puzzled here since there's an infinity summation. If i let $\theta$ to be in the equation, I think I can get both the sin and cos series approximation? But the thing is these approximations are signed (i.e. they have negative numbers) instead of purely just positive.
2. Even so, I'm unable to remove the $M^n$ factor. I tried to do a matrix multiplciation of $M^2$ and couldn't find any discernable pattern.
3. perhaps i need to use fourier series?

Comment: I don't see how you'd expect to see a pattern in the powers of $M$ from _one_ power. Work out $M^3$. You should get $M^3=-M$. So the sequence $M,M^2,M^3,\dots$ is just $M, M^2,-M,-M^2,M, M^2,-M,-M^2,\dots$.

Answer (score 2):

Note that $M$ is diagonalizable, i.e.,
$$
M=P^{-1}\Lambda P,
$$
where
$$
P=\left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
0&-i&1\\
0&i&1\\
1&0&0
\end{array}
\right),\quad\Lambda=\left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
-i&0&0\\
0&i&0\\
0&0&0
\end{array}
\right).
$$
Thanks to this result, we have
$$
\exp\left(\theta M\right)=\exp\left[P^{-1}\left(\theta\Lambda\right)P\right]=P^{-1}\exp\left(\theta\Lambda\right)P,
$$
where
$$
\exp\left(\theta\Lambda\right)=\exp\left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
-i\theta&0&0\\
0&i\theta&0\\
0&0&0
\end{array}
\right)=\left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
e^{-i\theta}&0&0\\
0&e^{i\theta}&0\\
0&0&1
\end{array}
\right).
$$

Comment: Great insight you have, but how do you know M is diagonalizable and how do you extract $P$ out?

Comment: @oldselflearner1959: This is the [diagonalizability of square matrices](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diagonalizable_matrix). A square matrix $M$ is called diagonalizable if it can be decomposed as $M=Q\Lambda Q^{-1}$ with $\Lambda$ being a diagonal matrix. A $n$-by-$n$ matrix is diagonalizable if and only if it has $n$ linearly independent eigenvectors.

Comment: @oldselflearner1959: Let $\left\{\mathbf{v}_j\right\}_{j=1}^n$ be a set of linearly independent eigenvectors of $M$ (column vectors here), such that $M\mathbf{v}_j=\lambda_j\mathbf{v}_j$. Then$$M\left(\mathbf{v}_1,\mathbf{v}_2,\cdots,\mathbf{v}_n\right)=\left(\mathbf{v}_1,\mathbf{v}_2,\cdots,\mathbf{v}_n\right)\text{diag}\left\{\lambda_1,\lambda_2,\cdots,\lambda_n\right\}.$$This is no more than $MQ=Q\Lambda$, or equivalently, $M=Q\Lambda Q^{-1}$.

Answer (score 2):

$$
e^{\theta M}=I+\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{\theta^{n}M^{n}}{n!}
$$

but the characteristic polynomial for $M$ is $M^{3}+M=0$ then

$$
I+\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{\theta^{n}M^{n}}{n!}=I+\frac{\theta M}{1!}+\frac{\theta^{2}M^{2}}{2!}-\frac{\theta^{3}M}{3!}-\frac{\theta^{4}M^{2}}{4!}+\cdots=I+M\left(\frac{\theta}{1!}-\frac{\theta^{3}}{3!}+\frac{\theta^{5}}{5!}+\cdots\right)+M^{2}\left(\frac{\theta^{2}}{2!}-\frac{\theta^{4}}{4!}+\frac{\theta^{6}}{6!}+\cdots\right)
$$

etc.

Answer (score 1):

We start by calculating several $M^n$ matrices
$$ M^1 =M = \begin{bmatrix}
0 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 1\\
0 & -1 & 0
\end{bmatrix}
$$
$$
M^2  = \begin{bmatrix}
0 & 0 & 0\\
0 & -1 & 0\\
0 & 0 & -1
\end{bmatrix}
$$
$$ M^3 =M^2M = \begin{bmatrix}
0 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & -1\\
0 & 1 & 0
\end{bmatrix}=-M
$$

$$
M^4  = M^2M^2=\begin{bmatrix}
0 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 1 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 1
\end{bmatrix}=-M^2
$$
By continuing this, you get $M^5=M$, $M^6=M^2$, ...

Now 
$$\exp \theta M = 1 + \sum^{\infty}_{n=1}\frac{\theta^n M^n}{n!}$$
We split this into odd and even powers of $n$
$$\exp \theta M=1+\sum^{\infty}_{n=1}\frac{\theta^{2n} M^{2n}}{(2n)!}+\sum^{\infty}_{n=0}\frac{\theta^{2n+1} M^{2n+1}}{(2n+1)!}$$
We can write the odd powers term as $$\sum^{\infty}_{n=0}\frac{\theta^{2n+1} M^{2n+1}}{(2n+1)!}=M\sum^{\infty}_{n=0}\frac{\theta^{2n+1} (-1)^{n}}{(2n+1)!}=M\sin\theta$$
Similarly,
$$\sum^{\infty}_{n=1}\frac{\theta^{2n} M^{2n}}{(2n)!}=M^2\sum^{\infty}_{n=1}\frac{\theta^{2n} (-1)^{n+1}}{(2n)!}=M^2\left(\sum^{\infty}_{n=1}\frac{\theta^{2n} (-1)^{n}}{(2n)!}+1-1\right)=M^2(1-\cos\theta)$$

Comment: Thanks for the insight I have got down part (a), but part b seems weird since I have to use the former result. More notably there's actually an integer plus a matrix - is this even valid? does the integer broadcast the value to all elements in the matrix?

Comment: That "integer" is the identity matrix.All zeros, except the diagonal, where everything is 1. For part b, you need to use some trigonometric identities, and write $M^3=-M$, and $M^4=-M^2$.  For part c, the identity matrix and $M^2$ are their own transpose, while $M^T=-M$.